# Toggling button with Bacon.js

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, bacon.js

So lets say I have a button `#button`. I want it to toggle visibility of some element `#element`. So with plain jQuery I would do

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {$("#element").toggle();})
```

Or with an explicit side-effect:

```
var visible = true;
$("#button").on("click", function() {visible = !visible; $("#element").show(visible);})
```

What would be the equivalent of this in Bacon.js. I would assume it's possible to do without any side-effects, but I can't figure it out how.

EDIT: Let me clarify: without any side-effect which aren't a part of Bacon.js-objects.

Comment: Without any side effects, you couldn't see anything on your screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs give an almost literal example on how to do that with [`.assign`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#property-assign) and [`$.fn.asEventStream`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#%24-aseventstream):

```
$("#button").asEventStream("click").assign($("#element"), "toggle");
```

Caveats: with an event stream you can't use the `Property::assign` method, yet `onValue` works the same way. Also we want to ensure that [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) isn't invoked with the event as an argument, so you'd rather use

```
$("#button").asEventStream("click").onValue($("#element"), "toggle", null, null);
```

---

For explicit state, we use the [`scan` method](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#observable-scan):

```
$("#button").asEventStream("click") // a stream of click events
.scan(true, // iterate it, starting with true
      function(visible, e) {
     // ignore the event parameter
     return !visible; // just toggle the boolean
}) // now we've got a property of a changing boolean value
.assign($("#element"), "show");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely positive about this, but it appears that Bacon.js relies on either jQuery or Zepto to function properly. From the API Documentation on GitHub:

> API Creating streams
>
> $.asEventStream(eventName) creates an EventStream from events on a
>   jQuery or Zepto.js object. You can pass optional arguments to add a
>   jQuery live selector and/or a function that processes the jQuery event
>   and its parameters, if given, like this:
>
> ```
> $("#my-div").asEventStream("click", ".more-specific-selector")
> $("#my-div").asEventStream("click", ".more-specific-selector", function(event, args) { return args[0] })
> $("#my-div").asEventStream("click", function(event, args) { return args[0] })
> ```

For what its worth, here's a fiddle that shows how you would do this in vanilla JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/cs01rm3v/